# Create Slack channel programmatically

Tags: curl, slack-api, slack

I don't see it in the documentation, but I was curious if anyone knew of a way within slack app to create a channel programmatically.

Here was my first attempt via slash commands via slackbot, but no success.

```
curl --data "/open test" https://xxxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/slackbot\?token\=xxxxxxxxx\&channel\=%23general
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create channels via the API using the `channels.join` method: https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.join.

```
This method is used to join a channel. If the channel does not exist, it is created.
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

You can also create new channels directly with the API method `channels.create`.

See the [documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.create) for more details